# need more memory on my phone

Tags: icloud, backup

I have the iphone 5 ios 6 and I have two backups on there and it tells me 
I need to delete one of my backups. Would this delete my stuff already on my device even if it says that it will delete  all backup data from icloud?

Answer (score 2):

No it will not delete the data from your phone. A backup is stored on your PC/Mac or on iCloud but the backup is just a reference copy of what is already on your phone. Deleting a backup will not delete the current data on your phone.

Answer (score 0):

If you need more memory on your iPhone 5 you could try resetting the iphone and delete everything, or known as try deleting all of the cache, Cache's are logs and files you don't need.

Make sure you have some iCloud Backups,

http://forums.imore.com/iphone-5/246764-how-clear-cache-make-ios-faster.html

http://www.pcmag.com/article2/0,2817,2401354,00.asp

http://ergonomics.hubpages.com/hub/6-Ways-to-Make-the-Most-Out-of-Your-iPhone-5

Comment: Answers on Ask Different need to be more than just a collection of links. It's okay to include links, but please summarize or excerpt them in the answer. The idea is to make the answer stand alone.